# Using BPF on a PCAP file

Tags: python, pcap, scapy

I have written a code which sniffs packets on the network. It then filters it according to the MAC address and stores it as a .pcap file. Now I want to add a function to the code which can read the .pcap file or the object that holds the sniffed packets to filter it again to get ARP packets.

I tried using PCAP library's bpf function but it doesn't help. Any other way this might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it all in python, I've used `dpkt` before and it works well: https://code.google.com/p/dpkt/

I don't know if it supports BPFs though.

Answer (score 1):

Open the pcap file with `pcap_open_offline()`, compile the filter `"arp"` with `pcap_compile()`, set the filter on the `pcap_t *` to the resulting filter with `pcap_setfilter()`, and then read the packets from that `pcap_t *`.